# Merge repo in foo/bar/ into repo at foo/

Tags: git

I've been working on a repo in `foo/bar/` for 2 months.

I've initialized a repo in `foo/`.

How do I merge the repo in `foo/bar/` into the one at `foo/` and retain history?

If this works, I no longer need to maintain `foo/bar/` independently as a submodule.

Comment: Merge as in keep all the files in the same place, but transfer the history to the outer repo?

Comment: You got it ___ @Ry

Comment: That’s `git subtree add`, then. Not sure about the specifics when the directory is already there, though. Is it currently an actual submodule?

Comment: It is not currently an actual submodule. Simply a repo.